# How can I capture :after content in IE8?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

I am applying an `:after` pseudo element to the body displaying the name of my media query breakpoint like so:

```css
body::after {
  content: 'medium';
  display: none;
}
```

The reason for doing this can be found here: http://adactio.com/journal/5429/

I want to get the content value of `:after` using javascript in IE8.

This is how i am doing it for other browsers:

```
var breakpoint = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':after').getPropertyValue('content');
```

But IE8 does not support `getComputedStyle()`, i know it supports `currentStyle` instead, but after a bit of trying i was unable to use it correctly.

This is the kind of thing i was trying with no success:

```
var breakpoint = document.body.currentStyle.getPropertyValue('content');
```

Anybody know how to do this?

**Edit:**
After BoltClock's note i have now changed my css to this (one semi colon):

```css
body:after {
  content: 'medium';
  display: none;
}
```

Before using two the content was not even appearing in IE8, so it would have had nothing to return. Unfortunately i still can't get IE8 to return the content.

I am trying this:

```
if (style = document.body.currentStyle) {
  for (var prop in style) {
    if (prop === 'content') {
      alert(prop);
    }
  }
}
```

I get nothing, but if i change `'content'` to some other property like `'backgroundColor'` it will alert something. So i'm thinking that even though msdn lists content as one of the available properties of `currentStyle` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it does not actually return it, unless i'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support the double-colon version of `::after` either. If you need to support IE8, use `:after`.

Comment: Thanks, i was hoping that would be the reason i couldn't get the value of the :after content but alas i still can't get ie8 to return anything.

Comment: Probably because `:after{}` does not count as the element's own style. Any chance you can use something like `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules`?

Comment: I'm afraid i was unable to get at it using document.styleSheets either.

Comment: Would you accept a solution with jQuery?

Comment: I think this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery

Comment: Yes i would accept a jquery answer but as far as i'm aware jquery cannot get the content of pseudo elements.

Comment: Please see link I've posted in corrected answer.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trying i've come to the conclusion that it is not possible. But thankfully i have found a js script which is achieving exactly what i was after.

https://github.com/JoshBarr/js-media-queries

As well as using Jeremy Keith's technique of putting the breakpoint label in the body:after they have put the breakpoint label in font-family on the html element. This enables support for ie8 and some cases where android was not able to return the :after content either.

Answer (score 0):

From IE7 to IE11, you can "create your own CSS Properties", and just access them by using the *currentStyle* object

Then a solution is to create a "fake content property"

```
body:after
{
    content: 'medium';
    -ms-content: 'medium';
}
```

I called it "-ms-content" for convenience, now your JavaScript code for IE should be:

```
document.body.currentStyle["-ms-content"] // RETURNS => 'medium'
```

> You must access "your own property" by using the brackets: currentStyle[{String}] otherwise you will get an empty string